# Unable to get user id from JSON using shared preferences

Tags: android, json

JSON DATA

```
{
    VerifiedMember: [{ user_id: "23", first_name: "karan", phone: "" }],
    success: 1,
    message: "success"
}
```

Login Activity Class

```
public class NewLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String PREFER_NAME = "Reg";

    Button btnLogin;
    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    // User Session Manager Class
    UserSessionManager session;

    String username;
    String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

        // User Session Manager
        session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "User Login Status: " + session.isUserLoggedIn(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view) {
        new loginAccess().execute();
    }

    private class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewLogin.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();

            // Get username, password from EditText
            String username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

            String url = "xxxx.xxx";
            JSONObject json;

            int successValue = 0;

            try {
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
                // Validate if username, password is filled
                if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){
                    String uName = null;
                    String uPassword =null;

                    if (sharedPreferences.contains("username")) {
                        uName = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
                    }

                    if (sharedPreferences.contains("password")) {
                        uPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");
                    }

                    if (username.equals(uName) && password.equals(uPassword)) {
                        session.createUserLoginSession("username", "password");
                    } else {

                    }
                }else{

                }

                Log.d("TESS :: ", json.toString());
                successValue = json.getInt("success");
                Log.d("Success Response :: ", String.valueOf(successValue));
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block flag=1;
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return String.valueOf(successValue);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonstring) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (jsonstring.equals("1")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, Sample.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(NewLogin.this, "Please enter the correct details!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample activity:

```
public class Sample extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL_DATA = "xxx.xxx";

    // User Session Manager Class
    UserSessionManager session;

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview);

        // Session class instance
        session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                loadRecyclerViewData();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(
                android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linaralayout1);

        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Sample.this, Post_data_Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        data_sAervers = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();
    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                String filename = "";
                String filetype = "";

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
                    if (posts != null && posts.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject fileObj = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                            String fName = fileObj.getString("firstname");
                            String created_at = fileObj.getString("created_at");
                            String post_desc = fileObj.getString("post_desc");

                            Log.e("Details", fName + "" + created_at + "" + post_desc);

                            JSONArray files = fileObj.getJSONArray("files");
                            if (files != null && files.length() > 0) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < files.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject Jsonfilename = files.getJSONObject(j);
                                    filename = Jsonfilename.getString("file_name");
                                    filetype = Jsonfilename.getString("file_type");

                                    if (filetype.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                                        filename = "xxx.xxx" + filename;
                                    } else if(filetype.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                        filename = "xxx.xxx" + filename;
                                    }

                                    Log.e("Files", "" + filename);
                                }
                            } else {
                                filename = "";
                                filetype = "";
                            }

                            Data_SAerver item = new Data_SAerver(fName, created_at, post_desc, filename, filetype);
                            data_sAervers.add(item);
                        }
                    }

                    adapter = new MyAdapter(data_sAervers, getApplicationContext());

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menuLogout:
                session.logoutUser();
                /*startActivity(new Intent(this, NewLogin.class));
                break;*/
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

MyAdapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers, Context context) {
        this.data_sAervers = data_sAervers;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Data_SAerver data_sAerver = data_sAervers.get(position);

        holder.firstname.setText(data_sAerver.getFirstname());
        holder.created_at.setText(data_sAerver.getCreated_at());
        holder.post_desc.setText(data_sAerver.getPost_desc());
        holder.filepathurl.setText(data_sAerver.getfilepath());

        if (data_sAerver.getFiletype().equals("1")) {
            holder.files.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(context).load(data_sAerver.getfilepath()).resize(736, 1128).onlyScaleDown().into(holder.files);
            holder.playvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            if (data_sAerver.getFiletype().equals("2")) {
                holder.playvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.files.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.playvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent play = new Intent(context, PlayVideo.class);
                        play.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        play.putExtra("url", data_sAerver.getfilepath());
                        context.startActivity(play);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data_sAervers.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // User Session Manager Class
        UserSessionManager session;

        public TextView firstname, commenttext;
        public TextView created_at;
        public TextView post_desc;
        public ImageView files;
        public LinearLayout comment_linear_layout;
        public TextView comment_btn;
        public TextView filepathurl;
        public TextView playvideo;
        // private TextView editTextUserName;
        public TextView onlinefirstname;
        Context con;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            filepathurl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.filepathurl);
            filepathurl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // editTextUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserrName);

            playvideo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.playvideo);
            firstname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            created_at = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.created_at);
            post_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            files = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_files);
            con = context;
            // onlinefirstname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.online_user_firstname);

            SparkButton sparkButton = (SparkButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.star_button1);
            sparkButton.setChecked(false);
            comment_btn = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);
            comment_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(con, Popup_layout.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    con.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

UserSessionManager:

```
public class UserSessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences reference
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor reference for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared preferences mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    public static final String PREFER_NAME = "Reg";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    public static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "username";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "firstname";
    // password
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    // Constructor
    public UserSessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    //Create login session
    public void createUserLoginSession(String uName, String uPassord){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, uName);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, uPassord);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method will check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else do anything
     * */
    public boolean checkLogin() {
        // Check login status
        if (!this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Sample.class);

            // Closing all the Activities from stack
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        //Use hashmap to store user credentials
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser() {
        // Clearing all user data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, NewLogin.class);

        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    // Check for login
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

Here I am not able to get `user_id` using shared preference. Please help me how to get it.

Comment: You didn't parse this

Comment: How to do i dont know pls let me know or give me some example code @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Know json parsing ??

Comment: not more little bit @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: can u add in my code pls @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Response);
JSONArray jre = jsonObject.getJSONArray("VerifiedMember");

                for (int j = 0; j < jre.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject jobject =jre.getJSONObject(j);

                    int   user_id = jobject.getInt("user_id");
                   

                }`

Comment: where should i add this code of line in my code can u edit it completly pls @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: where you get `JSON DATA` .According to your question .

Comment: oki now i want to login using that user_id ? can u help me in this ? @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 0):

In onPostExecute try this you will get User ID

```
       try {
        String userid;
        JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
        JSONArray arr = ob.getJSONArray("VerifiedMember");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            userid=obj.getString("user_id");

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: Where In sample Activty or Login Activity @deepak

Comment: in Login Activity

Comment: can  u added it for me pls

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pojo generator

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

For parsing you can use google's gson library or jackson parser is also good.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html